# Entities inside @Embeddable ignoring cascade annotation when used as @EmbeddedId

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I don't like posting a question that has been asked 1000 times just as much (if not more) as you don't like reading these repeated questions... but I'm currently stumped.  I don't understand why the typical solution in all these posts, namely using `'CascadeType.ALL'`, doesn't work here --

**Composite Key**

```
@Entity
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(selectBeforeUpdate = true, dynamicUpdate = true, dynamicInsert = true)
@Table(name = "A")
@SequenceGenerator(initialValue = 1, name = "a_id_gen", sequenceName = "a_id_seq")
public class ABean {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "ID")
  @Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "a_id_gen")
  private long id;

  @Column(name = "NAME")
  private String name;

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

-

```
@Embeddable
public class MainPrimaryKey implements Serializable {

  @JoinColumn(name = "A_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", insertable = true, updatable = true, nullable = false)
  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private ABean a;

  public ABean getABean() {
    return a;
  }

  public void setABean(ABean a) {
    this.a = a;
  }
}
```

**Entity**

```
@Entity
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(selectBeforeUpdate = true, dynamicUpdate = true, dynamicInsert = true)
@Table(name = "Main", schema = "public")
public class Main implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 3028687015173402553L;

  @Column(name = "A_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private Integer aId;

  @EmbeddedId
  private MainPrimaryKey pk;

  public MainPrimaryKey getPrimaryKey() {
    return pk;
  }

  public void setPrimaryKey(MainPrimaryKey pk) {
    this.pk = pk;
  }
}
```

**Adding a new entity**

```
MainDao dao = [...]

// ...

MainPrimaryKey key = new MainPrimaryKey();

ABean aBean = new ABean();
aBean.setName("pinto");

key.setABean(aBean);

Main main = new Main();
main.setPrimaryKey(key);

dao.add(main);
```

**Error**

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.blah.persistence.ABean; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.blah.persistence.ABean
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:654)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:793)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:664)
[...]
```

Obviously the work-around is to save all the dependencies first.  However, I definitely don't want to have to do that for all the entities that exist in the actual code.

Any ideas on what is missing/wrong here?

Comment: BTW just to clarify, there is more than one entity in the actual version/equivalent of "MainPrimaryKey"... I only put one in the example for brevity.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue could be this:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
@Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "a_id_gen")
private long id;
```

Because the ID of ABean is only generated once it is flushed to database it is transient (no id). So before saving `Main` you need to save ABean and then save main.

I suggest you remove `@Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)`. Normally you really don't want that! I do it like this:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO,
        generator = "sequence_generator")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sequence_generator",
        sequenceName = "my_sequence", allocationSize = 100)
@Column(name = "composition_id")
private Long id;
```

`allocationSize` determines how many sequence values are cached in the application. Hence no database trip is required for every single insert to associated an id with a new entity.